# React hooks: How do I update state on a nested object with useState()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, destructuring

I have a component that receives a prop that looks like this:

```
const styles = {
    font: {
        size: {
            value: '22',
            unit: 'px'
        },
        weight: 'bold',
        color: '#663300',
        family: 'arial',
        align: 'center'
    }
};
```

I'm trying to update the `align` property, but when I try to update the object, I wind up replacing the whole object with just the `align` property.

this is how I'm updating it:

```
const { ...styling } = styles;
const [style, setStyle] = useState(styling);

return (
        <RadioButtonGroup
            onChange={(event) => {
                setStyle({ ...style, font: { align: event.target.value } });
                console.log(style);
            }}
        />);
```

When I console.log `style` I just get `{"font":{"align":"left"}}` back.
I expected to see the whole object with the updated value for `align`. I'm new to destructuring so what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You need to use spread syntax to copy the font object properties too. Also while trying to update current state based on previous, use the callback pattern

```
<RadioButtonGroup
  onChange={(event) => { 
    setStyle(prevStyle => ({
        ...prevStyle,
        font: { ...prevStyle.font, align: event.target.value }
    }));
    console.log(style);
  }}
/>
```

Comment: I tried the solution, it is updating the object ok but I keep getting the following error in console.log
-------
react-dom.development.js:506 Warning: calculateChangedBits: Expected the return value to be a 31-bit integer. Instead received: undefined
    in App-------
Can you please assist in answer?

Answer (score 8):

This is your mistake

```
setStyle({
    ...style,
    font: { align: event.target.value } // This code replace the font object
});
```

To preserve the all `font` object values, you can do like this

```
const onChange = (event) => {
    const s = {...style};
    s.font.align = event.target.value;
    setStyle(s);
}
```

Or

```
const onChange = (event) => {
    setStyle({ 
        ...style,
        font: {
            ...style.font, // Spread the font object to preserve all values
            align: event.target.value
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I tried all answers and this was the only one that updated the object property without replacing the entire object. Thanks tolotra ;)

Comment: @tolotra In the object copy line `const s = {...style};` why is it declared using `const` and not `let` ?  Shouldn't the code fail when you try to modify the property of a const object?

Comment: @Ergin In JavaScript/TypeScript, a variable declared with `const` is not deep readonly like in C# or Java, it's only affect the delared variable, if I want to reassign value to my variable `s`, (like this: s = "a new object with a same shape or whatever you want"), it doesn't works. But if I want to reassign a value for a property of `s`, it works, like I did before.

Comment: Understood ok thanks for the explanation re: how JS defines `const`, appreciate it!

Answer (score 5):

If you have multiple values in a nested object, try this method below:

```
setPost({
  ...post,
  postDetails: {
    ...post.postDetails,
    [event.target.name]: event.target.value,
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can update the styles in this manner

```
onChange={(event) => {
    const s = {...styles};
    s.font.align = event.target.value;
    setStyle(s);
    console.log(style);
}}
```

Comment: This mutates the current state.

Answer (score -1):

Your code for default useState is invalid.
You should write like below for default useState:

```
  const { ...styling } = styles;
  const [style, setStyle] = useState({ styling }); // styling should be use in {}

return (
        <RadioButtonGroup
          onChange={event => {
            setStyle({
              ...styling,
              font: { ...styling.font, align: event.target.value }
            });
            console.log(style);
          }}
        />);
```

Demo:
check this demo with `console.log`.

[image: Edit awesome-diffie-pflqz]

Comment: Thanks, but this throws the following error: `This synthetic event is reused for performance reasons. If you're seeing this, you're accessing the property 'target' on a released/nullified synthetic event. This is set to null.` It also shows the same error in your codesandbox link.

Comment: @codemon Sorry, I changed demo after insert in answer. check demo again.

Answer (score -1):

First: 
`const { ...styling } = styles;`
is the same as:
`const styling = styles;`

But you may skip that altogether, just use `[...] = useState(styles)`

`setStyle()` accepts a function which receives the current state, in your case style.
So you may use the spread operator `...` to create new object and add values to it.

`setStyle(style => ({ ...style, font: { ...style.font, align: event.target.value } ) ) );`

Above code uses Arrow function, this could also be written as a normal function, but probably easier to understand:

```
setStyle( function (style) {
    return  {
        ...style,
        font: {
            ...style.font,
            align: 'center'
        }
    }
});
```

Your `console.log` in `setStyle` displays current style, as changed style will be seen on next render. So I've moved the `console.log` before return.

```
const [style, setStyle] = useState(styles);

console.log(style);

return (
        <RadioButtonGroup
            onChange={(event) => {
                setStyle(style => ({ ...style, font: { ...style.font, align: event.target.value } ) ) );
            }}
        />);
```

Here are some links to help you understand all that:

- Spread operator: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax
- useState hook: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html
- Arrow functions: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: What does `[...] = useState(styles)` do?

Comment: [...] is just a placeholder for your: [ style, setStyle ] = useState(styles), so I didn't write the whole thing.