# More elegant way of checking all state values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-state

Is there a more elegant way of checking all state variables in my react app ? I currently have 14 state variables within my app, I am checking the value of each and updating to an empty string if they do not pass validation (left empty) code is as:

```
  const [customerName, setCustomerName] = useState(null)
  const [customerPhone, setCustomerPhone] = useState(null)
  const [customerEmail, setCustomerEmail] = useState(null)
  const [customerAddress, setCustomerAddress] = useState(null)
  const [customerPostal, setCustomerPostal] = useState(null)
  const [purchasePrice, setPurchasePrice] = useState(null)
  const [colleagueName, setColleagueName] = useState(null)
  const [branch, setBranch] = useState(null)
  const [branchPhone, setBranchPhone] = useState(null)
  const [otherCompany, setOtherCompany] = useState(null)
  const [furtherInformation, setFurtherInformation] = useState(null)

 function submission() {
    if (customerName === null) {
        setCustomerName('')
    }
    if (customerPhone === null) {
        setCustomerPhone('')
    }
    if (customerEmail === null) {
      setCustomerEmail('')
    }
    if (customerAddress === null) {
      setCustomerAddress('')
    }
    if (customerPostal === null) {
      setCustomerPostal('')
    }
    if (purchasePrice === null) {
      setPurchasePrice('')
    }
    if (surveyType === null) {
      setSurveyType('')
    }
    if (colleagueName === null) {
      setColleagueName('')
    }
    if (branch === null) {
      setBranch('')
    }
    if (branchPhone === null) {
      setBranchPhone('')
    }
    if (company === null) {
      setCompany('')
    }
    if (company === 'Other' && otherCompany===null) {
      setCompany('Other')
      setOtherCompany('')
    }
    if (
      customerName !== ''
      && customerPhone !== ''
      && customerEmail !== ''
      && customerAddress !== ''
      && customerPostal !== ''
      && purchasePrice !== ''
      && surveyType !== ''
      && colleagueName !== ''
      && branch !== ''
      && branchPhone !== ''
      && company !== ''
      && otherCompany !== ''
    ){
      console.log('validation passed')
    }

  };
```

This **does** work, so its not the end of the world, but it just seems as though its not very elegant and I feel like there could be a more concise remedy out there?

Thanks

Comment: If you need the data to be an empty string instead of `null`, you could just initialize the `useStates` that way. Or in the validation you could just do simply falsy checks instead of strict equality so that `null` or `''` gets treated the same?

Comment: It could also clean up the code a bit to flatten out all the customer/state information into a single temporary string and check if that one string is empty.

Comment: @BrianThompson - I don't need them to be one over the other, I am using the two just for the differentiation between when the page loads (states initialised to null)  and the point at which submit is pressed. If I have the error conditional looking for null, they would all error on page load as they render empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something along these lines. As all these state variables seem to be tightly coupled. I don't see why they can't be one object.

```js
const [sale, setSale] = useState({
  customerName: '',
  customerPhone: '',
  customerEmail: '',
  customerAddress: '',
  customerPostal: '',
  purchasePrice: '',
  surveyType: '',
  colleagueName: '',
  branch: '',
  branchPhone: '',
  company: '',
  otherCompany: '',
})

const checksPasssed = Object.values(sale).every(v => v)
```

If you need to update one of them you can use spread.

```js
setSale({...sale, company: 'yahoo'})
```

Answer (score 0):

Options:

1. Use [`useReducer()`
   hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer).
   From the docs:

   > useReducer is usually preferable to useState when you have complex
   > state logic that involves multiple sub-values or when the next state
   > depends on the previous one. useReducer also lets you optimize
   > performance for components that trigger deep updates because [you can
   > pass dispatch down instead of callbacks.](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-to-avoid-passing-callbacks-down)
2. Use some kind of state management like [Redux](https://redux.js.org/) - if this state needs to be accessed by other components also. You can also use [Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html).
3. You can put all this state [in a single nested object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56802862/11667949) & then use
   useState:

   ```
   const [nestedState, setNestedState] = useState({
     a: 1,
     b: 'Shivam',
     c: {
       name: 'Sj',
       age: '20',
     },
   });

   // Then use `setnestedState()`:

   setNestedState(prevState => ({
     ...prevState,
     c: {
       ...prevState.c,
       age: 22,
     },
   }));
   ```